# Power saving with free Radeon (ATI) driver

Tags: drivers, ati, power-management, radeon

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 without the proprietary driver for ATI video cards and I like very much the performance.

My only need is activate power saving when I use the laptop with the battery.
Thanks

Comment: You can also look TLP which has power saving for ATI http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this blog](http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-open-source-ati-radeon-driver-power-usage-tweaks/)

You have two options, both involve editing `/etc/init.d/ati-power-save` options

```
gksu gedit /etc/init.d/ati-power-save
```

> First method is called “dynpm” and the second method is called “profile” method.

**dynpm method**

---

> Dynpm method is more modern and efficient but it might not work with some hardware combinations (like mine for example).

Add these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ATI power save
echo dynpm > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

Reboot

**Profile method**

---

> Power profile method is based on four power profiles you choose manually or at boot time using script like the one we are creating here. You can choose between 1. “default” 2. “auto” 3. “low” 4. “high”.

Add these lines to the file

```
#!/bin/sh

# ATI power save
echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

Reboot

**Either method**

---

Save the script and make it executable

```
chmod a+x /etc/init.d/ati-power-save
```

See the blog for additional details.

Comment: dynpm method made my DELL 1555 laptop fans finally go lower. I use Ubuntu 12.10 & radeon drivers (xorg-edgers version)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this command after making the script executable:

```
sudo update-rc.d ati-power-save defaults 99
```

It creates the links in /etc/rc?.d required to have it executed at startup.