# Ubuntu 12.04 Making Laptop super hot

Tags: 12.04, drivers, dual-boot, graphics, overheating

Hello I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (dual boot with windows.)
The laptop is getting really hot and fan starts running wildly on Ubuntu even if no applications are open.Windows 7 is running absolutely fine.No heating issue
This thus lead to sudden shutdown of laptop

Laptop Dell Studio 15 R RAM-4gb intel i5 processor

Graphic Card ATI Radeon 0.5 gb

Ubuntu Disk Space-20 gb

I searched the forum but and concluded either its a kernel problem or graphic problem
  I think may be its a graphic issue and hereby i attach an image which i think may be useful.Do I need to install this drivers?

Link:[Additional Driver Settings](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1RI4GvkHLjp6fsn_r6f7KRzxOMkaueVaEfdWDfhLKdkM/edit)

What can be the reason and how can i solve the heating issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's your GPU. By default, you are using the open-source ATI driver, which does not have any power saving options on after a clean install.

You have **two** choices:
 1) Install the proprietary driver.
 2) Add power saving to the open-source one.

1) Is easy. Go to the "Hardware Drivers" manager. Install your drivers.
2) Not much harder.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI#With_KMS_enabled

I'll copy out the main parts.
Open up a Terminal.
`# sudo su`
`# echo dynpm > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method`

This will instantly lower the temperature, and power consumption.
Should be noticeable after a while. Check if it works. If it does,
[read the corresponding answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96865/power-saving-with-free-radeon-ati-driver)

Comment: NOTE: Your card is not supported by the proprietary driver nowadays, so you should just stick to the open-source one. If you don't play games and such, it works perfectly. I use it too.