# Heating problems in HP Pavilion g6 AMD Vision A10

Tags: overheating, low-power

I have istalled TLP and AMD propreitary drivers (AMD Catalyst). But still the heating problem persists. Installing the above 2 helped a little by cooling to 3-5 degrees.

but still the cpu temp is greater than 60 degrees. and battery is draining much fast than windows 8.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/302440/ubuntu-12-04-making-laptop-super-hot