# How can I change my graphics card power profile?

Tags: graphics, power-management, radeon

The fan on my card is noticeably louder in ubuntu than in windows.

I suspect this is because it's running on a medium / high power profile, how can I change it to low?

Video card: Radeon 9670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article should provide you all the information you need to fix this issue:

[Power saving with free Radeon (ATI) driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96865/power-saving-with-free-radeon-ati-driver)

You can also change your CPU power profile while you are at it:

[Ubuntu, CPU Scaling, Battery life and You](http://arsgeek.hubpages.com/hub/Ubuntu--CPU-Scaling--Battery-life-and-You)