# power method script not running on startup

Tags: ati, power-management, radeon

I recently made [this entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362212/how-can-i-change-my-graphics-card-power-profile) asking about power profile. I followed the instructions which were [liked in the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96865/power-saving-with-free-radeon-ati-driver). It worked. However it is not longer working after I reinstalled grub. This is what I did:

```
gksu gedit /etc/init.d/ati-power-save
```

saved file with this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ATI power save
echo dynpm > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

ran this command:

```
chmod a+x /etc/init.d/ati-power-save
```

And it works when I just run the `echo dynpm ...` command. I see a flicker and can hear the fan slowing down. However it is not saved between reboots, when I restart my computer the previous power profile is set to default and I have to run the command again.

Running `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method` prints `profile` instead of `dynpm`

How can I make the setting permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `power_method` has restricted permissions.

Add the line

```
echo dynpm > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

to

```
/etc/rc.local
```

And the command will be run with sudo privileges on startup.