# Setting power profile on radeo driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, radeon

I am trying to change the power profile on my ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4530 in order to prevent overheating.

I'm following instructions which say to do the following:

```
sudo sh -c "echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method"
sudo sh -c "echo mid > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile "
```

However when I try and run this I get the following error

```
sh: 1: cannot create /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method: Directory nonexistent
```

How can I change the power profile so my laptop doesn't overheat?

Comment: Could you post a link to the instruction?

Comment: here is one example there are lots of others http://askubuntu.com/questions/96865/power-saving-with-free-radeon-ati-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the AMD Catalyst driver was still installed, the system wasn't using it because my card is no longer supported, however it was still installed and this was in some way preventing /sys/class/drm from being there.

I uninstalled the AMD Catalyst driver and rebooted and after that I could change the power profile.

The good news is after running that command my temp dropped 15 degrees.

Comment: I had even better performance by adding `radeon.dpm=1` in the boot options. http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395 ... but I do not know if it will be useful with your kernel. HTH